# I want to write journalInfo in italic pattern, what do I have to use instead of \bfseries?

Tags: formatting

```
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\ \scriptsize\@Archive\par}%
```

I want to write journal info in italic pattern. What do I have to use instead of `\bfseries`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code we can test. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Do you just want `\itshape`?

Comment: Can this question be closed as it is essentially repeated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689954/which-font-is-used-for-cursive-writing-in-latex ?