# Which font is used for cursive writing in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

Which font is used for cursive writing in LaTeX?
`{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\itshape\@JournalInfo\\ \scriptsize\@Archive\par}`

Here, `sffamily` I think it is for font. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? `\itshape` turns on italic, was that you question?

Comment: Note that "font" in the traditional (La)TeX context means a very specific style of font family. For example, sans-serif bold italic typeset in 10pt would be a different font than sans-serif bold typeset in 10pt or even sans-serif bold italic typeset in 12pt. Which font exactly is chosen also depends on the typeface you select (which you don't show in the code snippet). The font selection mechanism also differs between traditional (La)TeX and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Thus, as its stands, your question can't easily be answered.

Answer (score 1):

What you provide is a command to tell the compiler how to typeset entries in *JournalInfo* and *Archive*, two locations defined somewhere in a class or preamble.

*JournalInfo* is typeset right aligned (`\raggedleft`) using a sans serif font (`sffamily`) set as *bold* (`\bfseries`) and *italics* (`\itshape`) in a smaller font size (`\small`) than the normal text.

The command `\sffamily` doesn't specify any particular font, just that that font needs to be part of a sans serif family. Look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) for available fonts in that family.